# javascript classes - is "this.varname" required for each use?

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript class like this:

```
function Foo() {
  this.x = 5;
  this.y = x + 10;
}
```

Does 'x' not get scoped to the instance of the class when I don't use '.this'? If so, how do we use callbacks then? I have something like:

```
function Foo() {
  this.x = 5;

  this.grok = function() {
    jQuery(blah).animate({
      ..,
      function(){
        x = 55;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

so jquery gives a chance for a callback, but how do I access the 'x' member variable of the parent class in that context then?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your specific case, you have to store a reference to `this` in another variable:

```
function Foo() {
  this.x = 5;

  this.grok = function() {
      var that = this;
      jQuery(blah).animate({
        ..,
        function(){
          that.x = 55;
        }
      });
  }
}
```

The anonymous function has access to all variables defined in `grok`. If you just use `x`, it would be a global variable.

Comment: Ok so also I need to always use "this." before each access of a member variable, right? Thanks

Comment: @user246114: Yes. But be aware in which scope you are (like in the `animate` callback function).

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to use another variable as a pointer to the *correct* this then use a closure to capture that variable:

```
function Foo() {
  this.x = 5;
  var foo_this = this;

  this.grok = function() {
    jQuery(blah).animate({
      ..,
      function(){
        foo_this.x = 55;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Some people like to use the variable name `that` whenever they point to `this`. I personally prefer to use `self`.